# Compute $\int_{0}^{e}\sin(\pi\ln(x))dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I've got this improper integral (calculating the value) and I have difficulties understanding the integration steps
$$\int_{0}^{e}\sin(\pi\ln(x))dx$$
I know that $\sin(\pi)=0$ and $\ln(0)$ is not defined.

So, I would use substitution, with $u=\ln(x)$ and $du=\frac{1}{x}dx$ and adjust the bounds:
$$\int_{\ln(0)}^{\ln(e)} e^u\sin(\pi u) du = \int_{-\infty}^1 e^u\sin(\pi u) du$$

My question is, how do I get the $e^u$? 
And then, how do I continue? 
For continuation I would use partial integration to calculate the integral, or this there a kind of trick/rule to calculate it?

Comment: If $u=\log x$, so that $du=\frac{1}{x}\,dx$, then $dx = x\,du = e^u\,du$.

Comment: Another way is to try to find an antiderivative. What's the derivative of $x\sin(\pi\ln(x))$? What about $x\cos(\pi\ln(x))$? (Just two functions that I feel might work — or, at least, some linear combination.)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Okay, up to $dx=x du$ I understand it, but I still don't get it why I then use $e^u$. Could you eplain that step?

Comment: Maybe shorter (and explaining the result obtained by other methods), note that $\sin(\pi\log x)$ is the imaginary part of $e^{i\pi\log x}=x^{i\pi}$ hence the integral is the imaginary part of $$\left.\frac{x^{i\pi+1}}{i\pi+1}\right|_0^e=-\frac{e+1}{i\pi+1},$$ from which the result follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the integral we want to evaluate:

$$I:=\int_{0}^{e}\sin(\pi \ln(x))\:\mathrm{d}x$$

We can make the substitution $u = \ln(x)$ and therefore $\mathrm{d}u = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x} \implies \mathrm{d}x = e^{u}\:\mathrm{d}u$. This gives us:

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{1}e^{u}\sin(\pi u)\:\mathrm{d}u$$

We can now integrate by parts with $w = \sin(\pi u)$, $v' = e^{u}$:

$$I=\left.e^{u}\sin(\pi u)\right|_{u=-\infty}^{1}-\pi\int_{-\infty}^{1}e^{u}\cos(\pi u)\:\mathrm{d}u$$

Integrating the integral by parts again, we get:

$$I = \left.e^{u}\sin(\pi u)\right|_{u=-\infty}^{1}-\left.\pi e^{u}\cos(\pi u)\right|_{u=-\infty}^{1} - \pi^{2}\int_{-\infty}^{1}e^{u}\sin(\pi u)\:\mathrm{d}u$$

But the last integral is just $I$ again, so we have:

$$(1+\pi^{2})I = \left.e^{u}\sin(\pi u)\right|_{u=-\infty}^{1}-\left.\pi e^{u}\cos(\pi u)\right|_{u=-\infty}^{1} = \pi e$$

Where we note that as $u\to-\infty$ the $e^{u}$ dominates, bringing the function to $0$. Therefore:

$$I=\frac{\pi e}{1+\pi^{2}}$$

Comment: Ah thanks, now it's clear to me, I just used partial integration and got up to the las line, where I got the original one. This helps a lot.

Comment: @ChristophS No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 5):

If $u=\log x$, so that $du=\frac{1}{x}\,dx$, then $dx = x\,du = e^u\,du$.

To continue, integration by parts gives:

$$ I=\int_{-\infty}^{1}e^u\,sin(\pi u)\,du = -\pi\int_{-\infty}^{1}e^u\cos(\pi u)\,du=\pi e-\pi^2\int_{-\infty}^{1}e^u\sin(\pi u)\,du\tag{1}$$
and $I=\pi e-\pi^2 I $ leads to:
$$ I = \color{red}{\frac{\pi e}{1+\pi^2}}.\tag{2}$$